Python ThreadingHTTPServer interacting with the main thread how to?
I am using Python 3.9 on a Raspberry Pi. I'm using a http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer so that I can run other tasks concurrently while handling HTTP requests. My needs are simple, so I don't want to implement my own server - the standard library server should be sufficient.
I create the server like so:
    localHttpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(("localhost", webPort), HTTPd.httpdServer)

Where HTTPd.httpdServer is a class that inherits BaseHTTPRequestHandler and implements do_GET() and do_POST() to interpret the appropriate requests:
    class httpdServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

        def do_GET(self):

        def do_POST(self):

I launch the thread using:
    try:
        serverThread = threading.Thread(target=localHttpd.serve_forever, daemon = True)
        serverThread.start()
        print("server started")

    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))

However, when the server receives a certain POST request, my script needs to intercept a value from the request (an integer which will be used as an index), which will be processed in the main thread.
How do I pass the value back to the main thread?
Normally I would expect to use queue.Queue for this, but the code that interprets the POST data is inside a class that inherits a predefined handler. So if I were to use a queue.Queue, how do I pass this through to the class above as I am launching the thread directly to serve_forever?
I have also looked up threading.Event() but none of the examples I have seen fit my situation, as the only access to the thread I have is from within the above class itself.
I also considered using a file and watching for changes, but I want to minimize reads and writes to the SD card on the Pi.

"I have also looked up Events()" - sorry, I can't guess what you're referring to here. Do you mean threading.Event? asyncio.Event? Something else? Also, to be clear: the idea is that some other code is always running to operate the machinery, and some HTTP requests will come in to signal changes in the operation? I don't understand what you mean about "passing through to the class above". If you were talking about the httpdServer instance, those callbacks are reached naturally. The problem is communicating from do_POST to the main thread.

Thanks @KarlKnechtel, indeed the first of the above '''threading.Event''' iswhat I have tried to understand, but the examples I have seen do not seem to apply to using the class handler. Yes to be clear the main thread controls the camera and processes image manipulation and also the paint process. Indeed the problem is passing something to the main thread from within the handler class '''do_POST''' or '''do_GET''' to trigger an update on the main thread. A cross thread variable or queue for instance that is thread safe.
